# location_updated_message cannot be resolved or is not a field

Tags: android, location, sample

I've been trying to understand the code provided in the android developer site.

https://developer.android.com/training/location/receive-location-updates.html#stop-updates

Which leads me to this github code.

https://github.com/googlesamples/android-play-location/tree/master/LocationUpdates

So I've been copy pasting it all into my app. With my own API key and such. But I'm getting this error at onLocationChanged method which it underlined location_updated_message.

The error is "location_updated_message cannot be resolved or is not a field. " What should i do?

```
package com.example.mappane;

import android.location.Location;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationListener;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationServices;


import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.util.Date;

/**
 * Getting Location Updates.
 *
 * Demonstrates how to use the Fused Location Provider API to get updates about a device's
 * location. The Fused Location Provider is part of the Google Play services location APIs.
 *
 * For a simpler example that shows the use of Google Play services to fetch the last known location
 * of a device, see
 * https://github.com/googlesamples/android-play-location/tree/master/BasicLocation.
 *
 * This sample uses Google Play services, but it does not require authentication. For a sample that
 * uses Google Play services for authentication, see
 * https://github.com/googlesamples/android-google-accounts/tree/master/QuickStart.
 */
public class MapActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements
        ConnectionCallbacks, OnConnectionFailedListener, LocationListener {

    protected static final String TAG = "location-updates-sample";

    /**
     * The desired interval for location updates. Inexact. Updates may be more or less frequent.
     */
    public static final long UPDATE_INTERVAL_IN_MILLISECONDS = 10000;

    /**
     * The fastest rate for active location updates. Exact. Updates will never be more frequent
     * than this value.
     */
    public static final long FASTEST_UPDATE_INTERVAL_IN_MILLISECONDS =
            UPDATE_INTERVAL_IN_MILLISECONDS / 2;

    // Keys for storing activity state in the Bundle.
    protected final static String REQUESTING_LOCATION_UPDATES_KEY = "requesting-location-updates-key";
    protected final static String LOCATION_KEY = "location-key";
    protected final static String LAST_UPDATED_TIME_STRING_KEY = "last-updated-time-string-key";
/**
 * Provides the entry point to Google Play services.
 */
protected GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;

/**
 * Stores parameters for requests to the FusedLocationProviderApi.
 */
protected LocationRequest mLocationRequest;

/**
 * Represents a geographical location.
 */
protected Location mCurrentLocation;

// UI Widgets.
protected Button mStartUpdatesButton;
protected Button mStopUpdatesButton;
protected TextView mLastUpdateTimeTextView;
protected TextView mLatitudeTextView;
protected TextView mLongitudeTextView;

/**
 * Tracks the status of the location updates request. Value changes when the user presses the
 * Start Updates and Stop Updates buttons.
 */
protected Boolean mRequestingLocationUpdates;

/**
 * Time when the location was updated represented as a String.
 */
protected String mLastUpdateTime;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_map);

    // Locate the UI widgets.
    mStartUpdatesButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.start_updates_button);
    mStopUpdatesButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.stop_updates_button);
    mLatitudeTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.latitude_text);
    mLongitudeTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.longitude_text);
    mLastUpdateTimeTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.last_update_time_text);

    mRequestingLocationUpdates = false;
    mLastUpdateTime = "";

    // Update values using data stored in the Bundle.
    updateValuesFromBundle(savedInstanceState);

    // Kick off the process of building a GoogleApiClient and requesting the LocationServices
    // API.
    buildGoogleApiClient();
}

/**
 * Updates fields based on data stored in the bundle.
 *
 * @param savedInstanceState The activity state saved in the Bundle.
 */
private void updateValuesFromBundle(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    Log.i(TAG, "Updating values from bundle");
    if (savedInstanceState != null) {
        // Update the value of mRequestingLocationUpdates from the Bundle, and make sure that
        // the Start Updates and Stop Updates buttons are correctly enabled or disabled.
        if (savedInstanceState.keySet().contains(REQUESTING_LOCATION_UPDATES_KEY)) {
            mRequestingLocationUpdates = savedInstanceState.getBoolean(
                    REQUESTING_LOCATION_UPDATES_KEY);
            setButtonsEnabledState();
        }

        // Update the value of mCurrentLocation from the Bundle and update the UI to show the
        // correct latitude and longitude.
        if (savedInstanceState.keySet().contains(LOCATION_KEY)) {
            // Since LOCATION_KEY was found in the Bundle, we can be sure that mCurrentLocation
            // is not null.
            mCurrentLocation = savedInstanceState.getParcelable(LOCATION_KEY);
        }

        // Update the value of mLastUpdateTime from the Bundle and update the UI.
        if (savedInstanceState.keySet().contains(LAST_UPDATED_TIME_STRING_KEY)) {
            mLastUpdateTime = savedInstanceState.getString(LAST_UPDATED_TIME_STRING_KEY);
        }
        updateUI();
    }
}

/**
 * Builds a GoogleApiClient. Uses the {@code #addApi} method to request the
 * LocationServices API.
 */
protected synchronized void buildGoogleApiClient() {
    Log.i(TAG, "Building GoogleApiClient");
    mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
            .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
            .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
            .addApi(LocationServices.API)
            .build();
    createLocationRequest();
}

/**
 * Sets up the location request. Android has two location request settings:
 * {@code ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION} and {@code ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION}. These settings control
 * the accuracy of the current location. This sample uses ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION, as defined in
 * the AndroidManifest.xml.
 * <p/>
 * When the ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION setting is specified, combined with a fast update
 * interval (5 seconds), the Fused Location Provider API returns location updates that are
 * accurate to within a few feet.
 * <p/>
 * These settings are appropriate for mapping applications that show real-time location
 * updates.
 */
protected void createLocationRequest() {
    mLocationRequest = new LocationRequest();

    // Sets the desired interval for active location updates. This interval is
    // inexact. You may not receive updates at all if no location sources are available, or
    // you may receive them slower than requested. You may also receive updates faster than
    // requested if other applications are requesting location at a faster interval.
    mLocationRequest.setInterval(UPDATE_INTERVAL_IN_MILLISECONDS);

    // Sets the fastest rate for active location updates. This interval is exact, and your
    // application will never receive updates faster than this value.
    mLocationRequest.setFastestInterval(FASTEST_UPDATE_INTERVAL_IN_MILLISECONDS);

    mLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
}

/**
 * Handles the Start Updates button and requests start of location updates. Does nothing if
 * updates have already been requested.
 */
public void startUpdatesButtonHandler(View view) {
    if (!mRequestingLocationUpdates) {
        mRequestingLocationUpdates = true;
        setButtonsEnabledState();
        startLocationUpdates();
    }
}

/**
 * Handles the Stop Updates button, and requests removal of location updates. Does nothing if
 * updates were not previously requested.
 */
public void stopUpdatesButtonHandler(View view) {
    if (mRequestingLocationUpdates) {
        mRequestingLocationUpdates = false;
        setButtonsEnabledState();
        stopLocationUpdates();
    }
}

/**
 * Requests location updates from the FusedLocationApi.
 */
protected void startLocationUpdates() {
    // The final argument to {@code requestLocationUpdates()} is a LocationListener
    // (http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/LocationListener.html).
    LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(
            mGoogleApiClient, mLocationRequest, this);
}

/**
 * Ensures that only one button is enabled at any time. The Start Updates button is enabled
 * if the user is not requesting location updates. The Stop Updates button is enabled if the
 * user is requesting location updates.
 */
private void setButtonsEnabledState() {
    if (mRequestingLocationUpdates) {
        mStartUpdatesButton.setEnabled(false);
        mStopUpdatesButton.setEnabled(true);
    } else {
        mStartUpdatesButton.setEnabled(true);
        mStopUpdatesButton.setEnabled(false);
    }
}

/**
 * Updates the latitude, the longitude, and the last location time in the UI.
 */
private void updateUI() {
    mLatitudeTextView.setText(String.valueOf(mCurrentLocation.getLatitude()));
    mLongitudeTextView.setText(String.valueOf(mCurrentLocation.getLongitude()));
    mLastUpdateTimeTextView.setText(mLastUpdateTime);
}

/**
 * Removes location updates from the FusedLocationApi.
 */
protected void stopLocationUpdates() {
    // It is a good practice to remove location requests when the activity is in a paused or
    // stopped state. Doing so helps battery performance and is especially
    // recommended in applications that request frequent location updates.

    // The final argument to {@code requestLocationUpdates()} is a     LocationListener
    // (http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/LocationListener.html).
        LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.removeLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, this);
}

@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    mGoogleApiClient.connect();
}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    // Within {@code onPause()}, we pause location updates, but leave the
    // connection to GoogleApiClient intact.  Here, we resume receiving
    // location updates if the user has requested them.

    if (mGoogleApiClient.isConnected() && mRequestingLocationUpdates) {
        startLocationUpdates();
    }
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    // Stop location updates to save battery, but don't disconnect the GoogleApiClient object.
    stopLocationUpdates();
}

@Override
protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    if (mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {
        mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
    }
}

/**
 * Runs when a GoogleApiClient object successfully connects.
 */
@Override
public void onConnected(Bundle connectionHint) {
    Log.i(TAG, "Connected to GoogleApiClient");

    // If the initial location was never previously requested, we use
    // FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation() to get it. If it was previously requested, we store
    // its value in the Bundle and check for it in onCreate(). We
    // do not request it again unless the user specifically requests location updates by pressing
    // the Start Updates button.
    //
    // Because we cache the value of the initial location in the Bundle, it means that if the
    // user launches the activity,
    // moves to a new location, and then changes the device orientation, the original location
    // is displayed as the activity is re-created.
    if (mCurrentLocation == null) {
        mCurrentLocation = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(mGoogleApiClient);
        mLastUpdateTime = DateFormat.getTimeInstance().format(new Date());
        updateUI();
    }

    // If the user presses the Start Updates button before GoogleApiClient connects, we set
    // mRequestingLocationUpdates to true (see startUpdatesButtonHandler()). Here, we check
    // the value of mRequestingLocationUpdates and if it is true, we start location updates.
    if (mRequestingLocationUpdates) {
        startLocationUpdates();
    }
}

/**
 * Callback that fires when the location changes.
 */
@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    mCurrentLocation = location;
    mLastUpdateTime = DateFormat.getTimeInstance().format(new Date());
    updateUI();

//THIS LINE
//LOCATION_UPDATED_MESSAGE is underlined

    Toast.makeText(this, getResources().getString(R.string.location_updated_message),
            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}

@Override
public void onConnectionSuspended(int cause) {
    // The connection to Google Play services was lost for some reason. We call connect() to
    // attempt to re-establish the connection.
    Log.i(TAG, "Connection suspended");
    mGoogleApiClient.connect();
}

@Override
public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult result) {
    // Refer to the javadoc for ConnectionResult to see what error codes might be returned in
    // onConnectionFailed.
    Log.i(TAG, "Connection failed: ConnectionResult.getErrorCode() = " + result.getErrorCode());
}


/**
 * Stores activity data in the Bundle.
 */
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    savedInstanceState.putBoolean(REQUESTING_LOCATION_UPDATES_KEY, mRequestingLocationUpdates);
    savedInstanceState.putParcelable(LOCATION_KEY, mCurrentLocation);
    savedInstanceState.putString(LAST_UPDATED_TIME_STRING_KEY, mLastUpdateTime);
    super.onSaveInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
}
}
```

This is the xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:padding="@dimen/layout_padding">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/latitude_text"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="74dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="44dp"
    android:text="TextView" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/longitude_text"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="64dp"
    android:text="TextView" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/start_updates_button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/stop_updates_button"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="58dp"
    android:text="start_updates_button" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/stop_updates_button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/start_updates_button"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="85dp"
    android:text="stop_updates_buttonn" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/last_update_time_text"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="23dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    android:text="TextView" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would guess that you forgot to put a strings.xml resource file with the string string resource named location_updated_message (the file name doesn't matter)

Comment: Yes. You. Are. Correct. I thought that strings.xml does not give that kind of error in java. Too newbie I think. Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

Go to your project folder and search for res->values->strings.xml then add 
string name="location_updated_message"> YOUR MESSAGE HERE />